# How does PayPal disable your browser's toolbar access when you ue the new Checkout buttons

Tags: javascript, asp.net, paypal

When you click on the PayPal Button in v2 of the API, the browser's toolbar etc is also greyed out and not accessible. It is re-enabled when the PayPal process finishes. The actions are the same as if it was a modal popup BUT it applies to the whole browser.

[image]

Presumably this is a function built into the PayPal API but I didn't think this was possible but it obviously is.

Anyone know the script to do this?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot of what you're seeing?

Comment: Does it do it in all browsers or just Firefox? I feel like PayPal and Firefox are on the same team...

Comment: @mwilson Yes, that seems to be the case. Only happens in Firefox.

Comment: They probably have something baked in then. I know Microsoft Edge has some stuff built in to do Microsoft stuff as well. Seems like a similar story.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that this is a Firefox specificity. I explain:

When you try to pay with a Paypal account, it opens a new browser window used to authenticate you to your Paypal account (so the website itself doesn't know what you're typing - security reason).

When Firefox launch this new window, it disable "parent" window interactions.

I don't have any source to prove this, but that's how some Electron's windows works so I think that's how it's working.

You should look at the **window.open** implementation in Firefox to be sure.

Comment: Read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) and whilst I'm no expert I think I could achieve the desired result.